# How to execute multiple statement with variables in C# OdbcCommand object

Tags: mysql, .net, ado.net, odbc

I want to execute below MySql queries at a time through OdbcCommand object within C# as dynamic query, it always fails:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; 

set @row=0;  

select * from 
                    (

select @row:=@row+1  as my____row_num,
cities.`cityid`,
cities.`cityname`,
cities.`countryid`,
cities.`countryname` , '1' as my____data_row_created  , '1' as 
my____data_row_updated  from `cities`    ) p
                    where my____row_num>=101 and  my____row_num<=200;  

SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ ;
```

I'm using below method to execute above MySql queries:

```
 ExcuteCommand(Sql)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OdbcCommand SQLCommand = new OdbcCommand(Sql);
        OdbcConnection Con = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            SQLCommand.Connection = Con;
            OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(SQLCommand);
            da.Fill(dt);
            Con.Close();
            Con.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                Con.Close();
            }
            catch { }

            throw;
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: "it always fails" - and what does it *say* when it fails? fails how?

Comment: That is not c#. I'm not even sure that is valid SQL. What is the actual code you are executing?

Comment: It certainly isn't valid PL/SQL.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson looks like mysql based on the `@row:=@row+1`

Comment: Yes, above are the MySql statements, and are working properly on MySql workbench.

Comment: It throws error: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.16-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from (select 1  as my____row_num, cities.`cityid`, cities.`cityname`, c' at line 2

Comment: @IrfanHabib frankly, you might need to debug this; the first thing I'd do is try taking out the isolation level hints, to see if that is the problem - I don't expect it to  be. After that, I'd try re-writing the query using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `LIMIT`

Comment: @MarcGravell - thanks, removed unrelated PL/SQL tag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to attempt to solve your MySQL problem, but your C# code can and should be written better, and since comments are not suited for codes, I thought I'd better write this as an answer.

So here is an improvement to your C# part:

```
DataTable FillDataTable(string sql)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    using(var con = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using(var command =  new OdbcCommand(sql, con))
        {
            using(var dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(SQLCommand))
            {
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }
        }
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

Points of interests:

- I've renamed your method to a more descriptive name. `ExecuteCommand` doesn't say anything about what this method does. `FillDataTable` is self explanatory.
- The `using` statement ensures the disposing of instances implementing the `IDisposable` interface - And almost all ADO.Net classes are implementing it.
  The disposing of an OdbcConnection also close it, so you don't need to explicitly close it yourself.
- There is no point of catching exceptions if you are not doing anything with them. The thumb rule is to [throw early, catch late.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231057/exceptions-why-throw-early-why-catch-late) (actually catch as soon as you can do something about it like write to log, show a message to the user, retry etc').
- DataAdapters implicitly opens the Connection object, no need to explicitly open it.

Other two improvements you can do are:

1. Have this method also accepts parameters.
2. Have this method also accept the `CommandType` as a parameter (currently, using a stored procedure with this will not work since the default value of `CommandType` is `Text`

So, an even better version would be this:

```
DataTable FillDataTable(string sql, CommandType commandType, params OdbcParameter[] parameters)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    using(var con = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using(var command =  new OdbcCommand(sql, con))
        {
            command.CommandType = commandType;
            command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            using(var dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(SQLCommand))
            {
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }
        }
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

If you want to improve that even further, You can have a look at my GitHub [ADONETHelper](https://github.com/Peled-Zohar/ADONETHelper) project - There I have a single private method for `Execute`, and the methods for filling data tables, filling data sets, execute non query etc' all use this single method.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution from [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number). While executing multiple dynamic MySql statements through ODBC in C# we have two options:

1. Execute separately every command
2. Use stored procedures

In my case I'm bound to use dynamic-quires because I'm having only read-access on database.

**Solution:**
Rather than Declaring variable and set it, I used another technique to use a session variable as a derived table and crossed join it with the main table. See the following query, in my scenario I changes to below MySql query code and removed both SET SESSION related code from the query, and it worked properly:

```
select * from 
                        (

    select @row:=@row+1  as my____row_num,
    cities.`cityid`,
    cities.`cityname`,
    cities.`countryid`,
    cities.`countryname` , '1' as my____data_row_created  , '1' as 
    my____data_row_updated  from `cities` ,(select @row:=0) as t      ) p
                        where my____row_num>=101 and  my____row_num<=200;
```

Comment: It's good you found the solution you need, +1 for that. But it seems to me your query is a simple pagination query - doesn't MySql has built in limit and offset?

Answer (score 0):

would you please try this instead

```
declare @row int
    set @row=0;  
    select * from 
                        (

    select SUM(@row,1) as my____row_num,
    cities.cityid as CityID,
    cities.cityname as CityName,
    cities.countryid as CountryID,
    cities.countryname as CountryName , 

    '1' as my____data_row_created  , '1' as my____data_row_updated  from cities) //i did not understand the meaning of this

    where (my____row_num BETWEEN 100 AND 200 )
```

### backEnd

```
 ExcuteCommand(Sql)
    {
<AddThis>ConnectionString= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourDataBaseLocation_OR_theConnectionCreatedViaProperties"].Connectionstring;</AddThis>
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     <deleteThis>   OdbcCommand SQLCommand = new OdbcCommand(Sql);</deletethis>
//You Need to add the connection you have used it and Odbc

//Command.CommandType= CommandType.StoredProcedure();
        OdbcConnection Con = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);
<AddThis>OdbcCommand SqlCommand  = new OdbcCommand(Sql,Con);</AddThis>
        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            SQLCommand.Connection = Con;
            OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(SQLCommand);
            da.Fill(dt);
<add this > SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();</Add this>
            Con.Close();
           <delete> Con.Dispose();</delete>
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                Con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }

            throw (e);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: my____data_row_created & my____data_row_updated are static fields which are required and need to be static value for 1 both.

Comment: I try to execute your MySql query on MySql-WorkBench it fails on SUM(@row,1) as my____row_num,